# How to transfer specific amount of tokens to each holder in Solidity when transaction happens?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

what is the most efficient way to split transfer amount of tokens to all holders so contract would not cost too much gas?

1. How to store/update addresses array efficiently?
2. How to iterate holders addresses?

Others parts how to do actual transfer is clear for me, but I do not know how to get holders list and how to efficiently iterate so it would not cost too much gas.